# Adder Algorithm for n 1-bit numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

suppose adding two numbers with `a` and `b` bits can be done in O(max{a,b}). we want to add `n` numbers (n 1-bit numbers i.e add n's 0 or 1). the cost of this algoithm is vary from input permutation to another permutation. what is the best and worst case of this algorithm?

i ran into this problem as an old- quiz on Computer Course.

We have two Solution:

1- Best Case and Worst Case can be in O(n)

2- Best in O(n) and Wost Case in O(n lg n)

Anyone could describe any pesudocode or algorithm for above two time order?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want an algorithm that "adds two numbers that have 'a' and 'b' bits", or do you want an algorithm that "adds 'n' 1-bit numbers"?

Comment: Unclear what you want, partly because of bad English I'm afraid. Can you rewrite?

Comment: How can it be O(log n)?  You have to inspect *every* element, so it must be at least O(n).

Comment: yes, Dear @OliverCharlesworth, you are right. can add any detail?

Comment: So is this about the depth of a constant-fan-in circuit or what's happening here? It's hard to get that `log` otherwise

Comment: It can be O(log^2(n)) if you are running this in parallel on n/2 CPUs.

Comment: Dear @harold, i'm wrong. i remove my bad figure.

Comment: Dear @Eran, it's not parallel. i'm wrong.

Comment: @MojiMoji is this your homework or something?

Comment: Dear @L.Butz, no i have a solution. it's 2013 midterm exam.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/918248/14578

Answer (score 0):

Answer is 1- Best and worst case it is O(n).
Best case, when all bits are 0, the order required is n - 1 or simply put O(n).
Worst case, when all bits are 1, the actual order is sum of n * (lg n - lg i) / 2 ^ (lg n - lg i)
i from n to 0. As i tends to 0, the resulting expression value will be small and so can be ignored. So the expression is like n/2 + n/4 * 2 + .... Again a linear growth with n. 

Adding more details:
Best case, when all bits are 0, adding them will never result in a no having more than 1 digit. (ie it always gives 0). therefore the order is O(n)
Worst case, when all bits are 1, adding first 2 bit will require O(1) The result will be 10. Now adding it with another bit will require O(2) and this way order can increase in case of worst case. Assume we split the input set into 2 number pairs and add them, in the first iteration all pairs would require O(1) and will result in 10. There are n/2 pairs so it is O(n/2). In the second iteration, we split the first iteration result set into 2 number pairs and add them. (Note now all nos are 10) So the order would be n/4 * O(2). i.e, O(n/2). In this way it is to be proceeded till the result set is exhausted. But when the value of n is very large, the contribution from 3 iteration onward can be ignored. So it just O(n/2) + O(n/2) , i.e O(n)

Comment: Dear @Parsanna, would you please add a bit more detail ?

Comment: this is an algorithm for solution 1. what about the solution 2, worst time in O(n lgn)?